# How to run specific tests with django-admin.py?

Tags: python, django, testing

I have an app located at `app/` and tests which reside at `app/tests/tests.py`. How can I run those tests with `django-admin.py`?

I tried `django-admin.py test app`, `django-admin.py test app.tests` and `django-admin.py test app.tests.tests` but with no success.

I add that I am also adding the `--settings` param to the above commands but cut it off for readability.

Comment: I made a reusable app over the weekend, and used https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework as a blueprint on how to test my reusable app.  If you're not intersted in the test loading hackery that they use, you could add `django-nose` as a test dependency and use that for test discovery.  I did not find an easy, straight-forward, or defacto way to test reusable apps.

Comment: I must use the `django-admin.py` command. I am looking for something simple, just specifying the tests to run, not that kind of hackery :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `manage.py` instead on `django-admin.py`. So run `./manage.py test app`

Comment: I don't have the `manage.py` file since it is a reusable app. I'm using `django-admin.py` with the `--settings` param, which should act the same as `manage.py`.

Comment: So what is the problem exactly? You can't point to the tests in the tests -directory? Do you have `__init__.py` in the tests -directory? If not, create it with the content `from tests import *`

Comment: If I do that, if fails to load some settings from the Django-CMS module, which is some versions backwards than the current one for compatibility. Anyway, I would need to manually select that test file from the command, is this possible?

Comment: I don't think you can select the test file. But you can select which test case or specific test to run. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/testing/overview/#running-tests

Comment: I saw that, but it seem to work only if there is a `tests.py` in the app root. Since I have that file in `tests/`, it doesn't work. Or am I missing something?

Comment: It works fine when testing a project, but I don't know if it works the same way when testing stand-alone apps. (You need to turn the tests-directory into a module with `__init__.py`.)

Comment: I did that, I have a `__init__.py` in `app/tests/` but nothing changes.

Comment: In `app/tests/__init__.py` try doing a `from foo_test_module import *`

Comment: This causes other issues to arise, that's why I was looking for a way of specifying the exact test file from `django-admin.py`'s test command.